# How do I solve ambiguities between fields and properties when using C# shorthand syntax?

Tags: c#, getter-setter, shorthand

I cannot figure out how to use the shorthand syntax without having variables that don't match or completely different names.

There is ambiguity between fields and properties, but if I name them differently I can't use the shorthand get; set; syntax. How do I fix this?

```
/// <summary>
/// A customer object
/// </summary>
public class Customer
{
    // These are fields
    private string name;
    private string address;
    private string city;
    private string province;
    private string postalCode;
    private string phoneNumber;
    private string emailAddress;

    // These are properties
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string province { get; set; }
    public string postalCode { get; set; }
    public string phoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string emailAddress { get; set; }

    // This is a constructor
    public Customer(string Name, string Address, string City, string Province, string PostalCode, string PhoneNumber, string EmailAddress)
    {
        name = Name;                    // Cannot determine if name is field or property
        address = Address;              // Cannot determine if address is field or property
        city = City;                    // Cannot determine if city is field or property
        province = Province;            // Cannot determine if province is field or property
        postalCode = PostalCode;        // Cannot determine if postalCode is field or property
        phoneNumber = PhoneNumber;      // Cannot determine if phoneNumber is field or property
        emailAddress = EmailAddress;    // Cannot determine if emailAddress is field or property
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you declare an auto-implemented property:

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```

It is **not necessary** to create a backing field. The compiler creates a hidden (inaccessible) backing field for the property on your behalf that can ***only*** be accessed through the property's `get` and `set` accessors. You don't have to even think about it.

So, from your code above, just remove the fields that are duplicated by auto-implemented properties.

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx

Comment: Is it bad practice to not create a backing field?

Comment: @Ben : No. It's bad practice to publicly expose fields. However, in the case that there is no logic around the setting and retrieving of the field (e.g. a standard property that simply sets a field and gets the field), the designers of C# recognised the syntactic redundancy of requiring a backing field, so created a convenient shorthand for doing exactly that without having to explicitly write it in the code. Use auto-props if they are appropriate. The illusion that the compiler gives you of not having a backing field is a good thing because it eliminates unnecessary noise in your code.

Comment: @Ben: To be clear, auto-props **do** have a backing field. You don't need to declare it, and you can't access it, but it still exists.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare Auto Property,the compiler generates the backing field for you.

ie. when you declare

> public string Name { get; set; }

the compiler would have a code like

```
private string name; //Your backing Field.you don't need it manually.
 public string Name
 {
    get
    {
        return this.name;
    }
    set
    {
        this.name = value;
    }
}
```